# WPF Tooltip binding not updating

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tooltip

Good afternoon all,
I have to work with a legacy Winforms application but I'd like to start migrating it to WPF. It doesn't have a tooltip control now so I'd like to use a WPF tooltip object.

I create a single global instance of a tooltip object. I've bound the controls within it and my application sets the datacontext of the tooltip. I can manually show and hide the tooltip just fine. The first time I hover over an object it picks up the bound data perfectly and works great. When I move over another control the tooltip datacontext is changed but the displayed data is never reloaded.

I tried implementing a property changed event and use the INotifyPropertyChanged interface in the object I bind to. It appears the wpf tooltip is not listening to the event.

I tried setting the binding mode to Oneway (it's a display only tooltip).

The tooltip is created programmatically:

```
// build the tooltip window.
System.Windows.Controls.Image img = new System.Windows.Controls.Image();
img.Width = 50;
img.Height = 60;

// bind the image
System.Windows.Data.Binding imageBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("PatientImage.Data");
imageBinding.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.OneWay;
imageBinding.Source = bed;
img.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.Image.SourceProperty, imageBinding);

// wrap image in a border
System.Windows.Controls.Border brdr = new System.Windows.Controls.Border();
brdr.BorderBrush = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;
brdr.Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(6);
brdr.Child = img;

System.Windows.Controls.WrapPanel wp = new System.Windows.Controls.WrapPanel();

System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock tb = new System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock();
tb.Background = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.LightBlue;
tb.Foreground = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue;

// bind the text block
System.Windows.Data.Binding textBlockBinding = new System.Windows.Data.Binding("TooltipText");
textBlockBinding.Mode = System.Windows.Data.BindingMode.OneWay;
textBlockBinding.Source = bed;
tb.SetBinding(System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.TextProperty, textBlockBinding);

wp.Children.Add(brdr);
wp.Children.Add(tb);

bedTooltip = new System.Windows.Controls.ToolTip();
bedTooltip.Content = wp;
```

Any idea why this doesn't work? Maybe I need to use a tooltip object for each control instead of a single global one as a workaround?

Comment: -- Well, if I make one tooltip per control it works. It's a workaround, but I'd still like to understand why it doesn't update if you change the DataContext property. Perhaps the tooltip object design was never intended to be used in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The bindings specify a `Source`, because of that they no longer "care" about the DataContext and hence the bindings do not update if anything other than the property itself on the source-object changes.